# Alignment of the sentences

Tags: horizontal-alignment

Has someone idea how I can align the sentences? For instance:

```
Step 2. Find the best sequence of these two jobs by calculating the makespan of         
        two alternative.
```

I want to begin the word `two` horizontally in the same position as `Find`.

I tried `\tab` but did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\step}[1]{%
  \sbox0{\bfseries Step #1. }%
  \noindent\hangindent=\wd0\box0\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\step{1}
Find the best sequence of these two jobs by calculating the makespan of two alternative.

\step{2}
Find the best sequence of these two jobs by calculating the makespan of two alternative.

Now normal text resumes, we have found the best sequence of these two jobs by calculating
the makespan of two alternative.
Now normal text resumes, we have found the best sequence of these two jobs by calculating
the makespan of two alternative.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is exactly the answer of my question.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

[image]

Aside: What is a makespan?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\ }l}
Step 2. & Find the best sequence of these \\ 
        & two jobs by calculating the makespan of two alternative. \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use of `tabbing` is one of the many ways.

```
\begin{tabbing}
  Step 2.\quad\= Find the best sequence of these two jobs by calculating the makespan of\\
  \>two alternative.
\end{tabbing}
```

However, for situations like this, I prefer to use the `description` 
environment.

```
...........
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[font=\normalfont]
\item [Step 2.] Find the best sequence of these two jobs by
  calculating the makespan of two alternative.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I add the answer which is exactly the same as egreg's answer but without LaTeX dependencies:

```
\def\step#1{\setbox0=\hbox{\bf Step #1. }%
   \noindent \hangindent=\wd0 \box0 \ignorespaces
}
```

The point is that this code is usable in all TeX formats (including LaTeX). I don't understand why people prefer the code with LaTeX dependencies which is a mix of LaTeX macros and primitives.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `linguex` with some advantages over make custom boxes:

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\ExLBr}{\bfseries Step }
\renewcommand{\ExRBr}{.}
\setlength{\parskip}{.2em}  % optional
\setlength{\Extopsep}{.5em} % optional

\section{Steps example}

Now a non indented paragraph of text because is after the nice title of of the section.

The start of this paragraph is highlighted by using the default indentation.

\ex. Find the best sequence of these two jobs by calculating the makespan of two alternative.

\ex. Note that vertical space among steps could be configured. 

This paragraph is not indented because is after the last step.  
But the next paragraph will be indented again.

Note that the step list might be continued at any some point of the text:

\ex. We return to the step list here. Note that some vertical space among steps could be optionally added. 

\ex. This is the last step. The list stop here.

\end{document}
```